# How to get an order Map wih AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer ?

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

I've used this stuff to get a List>, which is very interesting to manipulate datas like a "resultSet". 
My method is : 
    requeteSQL.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);

When i execute this query with sqldevelopper, i have got for exemple
        | Field 1 | Field 2 
 Line 1 | Value 1 | Value 2

But my map is not in the righ order ? 
How to fix this error ? And why my map have Field2 = Value2, Field1 = Value1 in this order ?

Comment: Can you show us your mapping ?

Answer (score 12):

because it hash map, how can you expect the order retrieval,if want order retrieval please implement your own ResultTransformer which will return LinkedHashMap e.g.

```
public class AliasToEntityOrderedMapResultTransformer extends AliasedTupleSubsetResultTransformer {

public static final AliasToEntityOrderedMapResultTransformer INSTANCE = new AliasToEntityOrderedMapResultTransformer();

/**
 * Disallow instantiation of AliasToEntityOrderedMapResultTransformer .
 */
private AliasToEntityOrderedMapResultTransformer () {
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
            /* please note here LinkedHashMap is used so hopefully u ll get ordered key */
    Map result = new LinkedHashMap(tuple.length);
    for ( int i=0; i<tuple.length; i++ ) {
        String alias = aliases[i];
        if ( alias!=null ) {
            result.put( alias, tuple[i] );
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public boolean isTransformedValueATupleElement(String[] aliases, int tupleLength) {
    return false;
}

/**
 * Serialization hook for ensuring singleton uniqueing.
 *
 * @return The singleton instance : {@link #INSTANCE}
 */
private Object readResolve() {
    return INSTANCE;
}
}
```

by the way your logic should not be depend of the order of keys it appear in resultant map.

Comment: "so hopefully u ll get ordered key ", hopefully mean not guarantee to follow the sql select fields ordering?