# Hibernate secure order of colums in native query

Tags: native

I'm trying to switch our project to Hibernate. The problem is in some places we rely on column order of ResultSet. But a query like:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> rows = session.createSQLQuery("select * from names")    
.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP).list();
```

gives me a list of Maps, which order of pairs  is undefined. That is, pair for "id" could appear as last one, while it is first in the table... 
How can I get column names in order like it is in native SQL?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem.

What helped me was the following stackoverflow question:
[How to get an order Map wih AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108267/how-to-get-an-order-map-wih-aliastoentitymapresulttransformer)

By extending AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer you can switch out the HashMap for a LinkedHashMap and preserve the order of your query result.